# Base-64 Plugin in Nativescript

Tags: typescript, paypal, oauth, base64, nativescript

I am looking for a way to get my OAuth Token from the PayPal API. I need to use the basic Authorization when passing my clientID:secret. Sadly the Base-64 Module is not available for NativeScript and the NativeScript-OAuth-Plugin does not provide encrypting data. What I am searching is a way or a workaround for the btoa-function (would be the easiest way) in JavaScript/Typescript. Does someone know a way to do that or maybe a plugin that i can use?

Comment: Are you wanting a solution for android or ios or both?

Comment: It should work for both if I can use it in NativeScript, shouldn't it? Anyway i need it for both, i should have mentioned it. Editing the question now :)

Comment: I have an answer for android, ive not looked at ios yet. I'll post the android answer and update it if i find the ios way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NativeScript actually provides a plugin for base-64 and utf-8 encoding. How to use and where to find them is described [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-base64-encode-a-string-in-nativescript/345).

Answer (score 3):

For android, you can do

```
android.util.Base64.decode(dataToDecode, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and add `declare var android` above your `@Component` in your ts file

Comment: Thanks for that one! But there is a more easy way i found out for NativeScript.

Comment: Really? This was is just 2 small lines of code and the plugins never seem to work

Comment: It worked for Android and iOS for me, are you having issues using it?  Yes that's just two lines of code, but it is plaform-dependent, isn't it? Since the other approach works for both Android and iOS, it is easier to use it (which is basically only 2 lines of code either), wouldn't you agree
?

Comment: I've had issues will all of the plugins and none of them seem to work. As for the platform dependent bit, i believe both can be done in 2-3 lines (not looked at ios yet) but still seem easier than plugins that dont work

Comment: Yeah there is code for iOS that is quite short, so it might be an alternative for everyone having issues with the plugin. Still all I did was installing the plugin, importing the package and it worked out fine for me. Did he give you an error? Did you maybe miss an import or something? I used the plugin to access the PayPal API and the authentication worked without any problems on first attempt.

Comment: So did i, they dont give me an error, it just does the same as if i tried to use the btoa() method direct from es5/6 etc

Comment: So it does not give you an error? So it worked the way it was supposed to work - most likely it did what was expected from that plugin. What is the problem with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151941/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-rudiger).